# unable to get cached values

Tags: java, web-services, caching, playframework

I am using play framework; and in the webservice call I had two webservice calls. For testing purpose I invoke the WS calls from a plain Java coding after running the play server. First WS sets the username in Cache and second WS call retieve it from the cache and returns to the plain Java code which I run to test. The thing is that when I call the second WS immediately after the first WS I can get the cached data. but if I call both WS calls seperately I get null pointer exception.I run WS1 first and comment out that calling line and after that I run again to invoke the WS2. during this time the server is runnning.

Comment: You should really post some code.